# WP ThirstyAffiliates plugin hook

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm using ThirstyAffiliates plugin and I need to do some changes in function thirstyRedirectUrl(). The trouble is after update plugin my changes will disappear. How and where can I make some hook?

My change is

```
if (isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] != '')
  $redirectUrl = apply_filters('thirstyFilterRedirectUrlToken', $redirectUrl, $_GET['token']);
else
  $redirectUrl = apply_filters('thirstyFilterRedirectUrl', $redirectUrl);
```

Here is all code of the function

```
function thirstyRedirectUrl() {
global $post;

if (get_post_type($post) == 'thirstylink') {
    // Get link data and set the redirect url
    $linkData = unserialize(get_post_meta($post->ID, 'thirstyData', true));
    $thirstyOptions = get_option('thirstyOptions');

    // Set redirect URL
    $redirectUrl = htmlspecialchars_decode($linkData['linkurl'], ENT_COMPAT);

    // Set redirect type
    $redirectType = $linkData['linkredirecttype'];
    if (empty($redirectType))
        $redirectType = $thirstyOptions['linkredirecttype'];

    // Apply any filters to the url before redirecting
    if (isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] != '')
        $redirectUrl = apply_filters('thirstyFilterRedirectUrlToken', $redirectUrl, $_GET['token']);
    else
        $redirectUrl = apply_filters('thirstyFilterRedirectUrl', $redirectUrl);
    $redirectType = apply_filters('thirstyFilterRedirectType', $redirectType);

    // Perform any actions before redirecting
    do_action('thirstyBeforeLinkRedirect', $post->ID, $redirectUrl, $redirectType);

    if (empty($redirectType))
        $redirectType = 301; // default to 301 redirect

    // Redirect the page
    if (!empty($redirectUrl))
        wp_redirect($redirectUrl, intval($redirectType));
    exit();
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% clear on what you're asking.  Is that the original plugin code?  If so, create functions in your theme add use `add_filter()` to call them with the same filter names (eg 'thirstyFilterRedirectUrlToken').  Your code would do in your theme, not in the plugin, so you should be able to update the plugin without a problem.  If you don't have your own theme, look at creating a [child theme](https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes) of the theme you're using, so you can keep your code when if you update the main theme.

Comment: @Hobo the changes in plugin /wp-content/plugins/thirstyaffiliates/thirstyaffiliates.php. And I want to use some hook in my child theme in functions.php, but I don't know how.

Comment: Sorry, you added code to the plugin?  Or you just want to know how to use the `thirstyFilterRedirectUrlToken` and `thirstyFilterRedirectUrl` hooks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had a look at the source code for the plugin.  I don't think it needs to be changed.  In fact, it *can't* be changed if you want to be able to upgrade it - you need to use the hooks the developers provide, and if they don't provide any you're out of luck.  That goes for all plugins, not just this one.

Roll back your changes, then add something like the following to your theme (untested, but it should point you in the right direction):

```
function myThirstyFilterRedirectUrl($redirecturl) {
    $result = ''; // a filter action needs to return a value
    if (isset($_GET['token']) && $_GET['token'] != '') {
        // Do your token processing here, and set $result
    }
    else {
        // Do your non-token processing here, and set $result
    }
    return $result;
}

add_filter('thirstyFilterRedirectUrl', 'myThirstyFilterRedirectUrl');
```